# Currency style not found error when opening excel created with xlwt python

Tags: python-2.7, excel-2007, odoo-10

I have created an excel file with python xlwt package.but when i open the file in excel 2007, a warning always pops up,it is telling me that the `currency style not found(percentage style also)`.In my code the particular  column is formatted with num_format_str,the corresponding code is below.(issue is with excel 2007,other versions like 2010,2013 working fine).

```
 percent_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})
 currency_fmt =  workbook.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0.00'})
```

someone please help to sort out this..